# C# Библиотека для отрисовки примитивов и текста на GPU

Tags: c#

Привет!
Понадобилось отрисовать большой и сложный граф.
Решение на GDI+ не устраивает своей медлительностью.
Подскажите пожалуйста какие-нибудь аналогичные варианты с отрисовкой на GPU?
Нужно рисовать полигоны, круги, линии и самое главное - текст как можно быстрее. Чтобы прокручивание мышкой и масштабирование графа не тормозило.

Comment: ну вопще-то DirectX/Direct2D - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2010/12/09/directx-and-net/

Comment: Ммм, SharpDX - это то, что надо!

Comment: может быть кому-то это и надо ;-)